# Change number of positional arguments in a function

Tags: python, arguments

I am new to python and I'm trying to create a program that will list out all the files in a folder and be able to parse through all the files.

I am getting this error **TypeError: Document() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given** and I am not sure how to fix it because I need those 2 arguments in Document(). Any help anyone can give is greatly appreciated!

```
import docx, os
from docx import Document
from os listdir

#1. List all documents in folder
paths = listdir(folderpath)


#2. Iterate through folder to continuously update the file path in the doc variable
i = 0
for i in range(0,len(paths)):
    filename = paths[i]
    print(filename)
    doc = Document(folderpath, filename) #folderpath + filename = filepath
    i = i+1
```

Comment: What gave you the idea that [`docx.Document`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#document-constructor) accepts 2 parameters?

Comment: Can you please correct the third import row ? should be `from os import listdir`. Further just as a general improvement suggestion you do not need i at all if you will never want to know that value, you can just iterate over path such as `for filename in paths:`

Comment: @d parolin  thank you for the suggestion! and @Matthias I was just researching different ways to go through a folder and list the files and one was I found was using dox.Document() but I wasn't sure how many arguments it accepted until I got the error and researched it more. Do you know of any way to use 2 parameters or of another module that could do the same thing using 2 parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the `docx` package, but the error message you are seeing is because you have supplied incorrect arguments to the `Document` constructor, see [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#document-constructor). `Document` takes one optional argument, either a path or a file-like object.

Instead of passing both path and filename, did you mean to concatenate them as your comment suggests?

Something like:

`doc = Document(folderpath + filename)`

should do the trick if they are correctly formatted. Otherwise you can look into [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).